# Writing a C++ Program to Search an Index File From the Linux Command Line

Tags: c++, linux, file, command-line, indexing

I've written a program that reads in a data file and creates a sorted index file from the data in the original file. However, I"m then supposed to write a second program that allows teh user to search this index file from the Linux command line. For example, they are supposed to be able to type

```
search 12382 prog5.idx
```

into the command line and have the information for that record displayed. I have no idea how to accomplish this.

I have written the code to create the index file (works):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Record {
    string name;
    int code;
    double cost;
public:
    Record() {
    }
    Record(string tname,int tcode,double tcost) : name(tname),code(tcode),cost(tcost) { 
    }
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &os, const Record& r);
};

//print function
ostream& operator<< (ostream &os, const Record& r) {
    os << setw(10) << r.name << " " << setw(5) << r.code << " $"  << setw(10) << setprecision(2) << fixed << r.cost ;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    std::map<int, Record> myMap;
    ifstream data;
    size_t offset_count = 0;
    data.open("prog5.dat");
    ofstream outFile("prog5.idx", ios::out);

    //if file can't be opened, exit
    if(!data) {
        cerr << "Open Failure" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(data, line)) {
        stringstream ss(line);
        int key;
        string name;
        int code;
        double cost;

        if(ss >> key >> name >> code >> cost) {
            Record r(name,code,cost);
            myMap.insert( pair<int,Record>(key,r));
        }
        else {
             cout << "Error";
        }
    }

    // print what's stored in map
    for(std::map<int,Record>::iterator x = myMap.begin(); x!=myMap.end(); ++x) {
        cout << setw(10) << x->first << ": " << x->second << endl;
    }
}
```

And get the following output when running the above code:

```
     8:      blank     0 $      0.00
 12165:     Item16    30 $      7.69
 12345:     Item06    45 $     14.20
 12382:     Item09    62 $     41.37
 12434:     Item04    21 $     17.30
 16541:     Item12    21 $      9.99
 21212:     Itme31    19 $      8.35
 34186:     Item25    18 $     17.75
 41742:     Item14    55 $     12.36
```

Here's what I have so far for the second program:

```
#include <prog3.idx>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc < 3) {
        std::cerr << "Too few arguments \n";
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int key = atoi(argv[1]);
    const char* filename = argv[2];
    ifstream input;
    input.open("prog5.idx");
}
```

But I'm not sure where to go from there. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use map or multimap and find in the STL. Make a datatype out of the remaining data with the index as the key. The program will have to read in the entire file first and then find the searched index.

Comment: And if you want to be really fast: use a vector<pair<Key, Val>> that is sorted and use binary_search (lower/upper_bound algorithms). Locality of reference will do the rest.

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea how to do any of that though :-/